# No exceptions occur in Socket.ReceiveTaskAsync and how to cancel it?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I've added an extention method "ReceiveTaskAsync" on the following.

```
public static Task<int> ReceiveTaskAsync(
    this Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(
          socket.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, count, SocketFlags.None, null, socket),
          socket.EndReceive);
}
```

And then, I called to "ReceivePacketAsync()" on the following. In the Method, I called to "client.Close()", but any exceptions like "System.ObjectDisposedException" NEVER occur at the next line. Why ever?

```
private async Task ReceivePacketAsync(Socket client)
{
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    client.Close();
    Task<int> ReceiveTask = await client.ReceiveTaskAsync(readBuffer, 0, 100);
}
```

I think I'll catch the exception "System.ObjectDisposedException" in order to cancel the "ReceiveTaskAsync" method.
Why the exception never occurs?

--Here is the code calls to ReceivePacketAsync--

```
public void Run(int port)
{
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
    listener.Listen(100);

    Task acceptClientTask = AcceptClientAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("The server is listening...");
}

private async Task AcceptClientAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Socket newClient = await listener.AcceptTaskAsync();
        Task receivePacketTask = ReceivePacketAsync(newClient);
        Console.WriteLine("New client has connected to the server.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `ReceiveTaskAsync` and then *ignoring* what it returns. you should change it to `await client.ReceiveTaskAsync(...)` and that might improve matters or might not (it depends on what the code calling `ReceivePacketAsync` looks like)

Comment: And, of course, the question occurs of why you're not just using [`ReceiveAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever // Ah. Thanks. I edited the code, But no exceptions still occur.
Just ReceiveAsync in the Socket is not a Task-Based method, So I'm not using it.

Comment: what I was kindof alluding to (and saying we'd need to see the code that *calls* `ReceivePacketAsync`) is that maybe it's also not waiting for the returned task to complete? Basically, you need to check all sites that are working with `Task`s of some variant and ensure that they're actually being *used*.

Comment: I added the code that calls to ReceivePacketAsync.

Comment: So, as I suggested in the previous comment, the problem is that the `Task` isn't being waited for. You seem to have some misunderstandingg of what `async`/`await` actually do. Maybe Eric Lippert's old [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx) will help to clear up some misconceptions.